# How to get shopify API in Salesforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api

I am trying to get the Shopify Api by using apex. I am unable to find any Connect Api call that returns to sandbox and import product data. Any suggestions how can this be achieved. Any suggestions regarding this would highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the shopify's API to get the required data.
This is the link that contains the guildlines of how to use the shopigy API.
https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/product